# What can be the possible cause of 'Unhandled Promise Rejection: TypeError' in aurelia?

Tags: typescript, http, request, aurelia

I have been into Aurelia development but took break for two months. Now I have started a new project in it and I am encountering an unknown issue when trying to use `http-fetch-client`.

Console shows:

```
aurelia-fetch-client.js?a909:199 OPTIONS http://url.com/api/login net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

index.js?07f7:248 Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection: TypeError: Failed to fetch
```

Network tab shows:

```
Request URL: http://url.com/api/login
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

To my surprise, my previous project (that was executing fetch client request successfully two months ago) is also showing this error now.
Can anyone give insight over this issue?
Why am I encountering this?

Comment: Your server is down.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're doing async/await, and you haven't wrapped your `await` call in a `try/catch`.

Some versions of Aurelia use Bluebird as a Promise shim, and you can use their [global rejection events](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/error-management-configuration.html#global-rejection-events) to deal with those problems.

Here's what that looks like.

```
// NOTE: event name is all lower case as per DOM convention
window.addEventListener("unhandledrejection", function(e) {
    // NOTE: e.preventDefault() must be manually called to prevent the default
    // action which is currently to log the stack trace to console.warn
    e.preventDefault();
    // NOTE: parameters are properties of the event detail property
    var reason = e.detail.reason;
    var promise = e.detail.promise;
    // See Promise.onPossiblyUnhandledRejection for parameter documentation
});

// NOTE: event name is all lower case as per DOM convention
window.addEventListener("rejectionhandled", function(e) {
    // NOTE: e.preventDefault() must be manually called prevent the default
    // action which is currently unset (but might be set to something in the future)
    e.preventDefault();
    // NOTE: parameters are properties of the event detail property
    var promise = e.detail.promise;
    // See Promise.onUnhandledRejectionHandled for parameter documentation
});
```

Of course, you might be using a different Promise shim. But, ultimately, `try/catch` is your answer.